# Verifying PM Installation Step in i2b2 not working

Tags: i2b2

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the Chapter 5 of the documentation for PM Installation which can be found [here](http://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/getstarted/5.7+Verify+PM+Installation).I am at step **5.7 Verify PM Installation Step**. And when I run the following URL as mentioned in the documentation `http://localhost:9090/i2b2/services/listServices`, I see a blank page. Basically it's 404 Not Found message I saw in the developer tools console window of chrome. I am not sure why the webservice is not running. I can see the JBoss running when I used the URL `localhost:9990` which eventually redirects me to the URL `http://localhost:9990/error/index_win.html`.

The following commands shows that my build was successful and everything went fine until **Deployment Step 5.5**

```
C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm>"%ANT_HOME%"\bin\ant.bat -f master_build.xml  clean build-all depl
oy
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\master_build.xml

common_init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\test-reports
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\genlib
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes

common_clean:
     [echo] Cleaning non-source directories in C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\genlib

clean:

common_init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\genlib
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes

common_clean:
     [echo] Cleaning non-source directories in C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\genlib

build-all:

common_init:

init:

compile:
    [javac] C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.server-common\build.xml:45: warning: 'includeantruntime'
was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

dist:
     [echo] i2b2Common: Creating the archive package!
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\genlib

dist:
     [echo] ProjectManagement: Creating the archive package!

common_init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes

common-classpath:

init:

jaxb_gen:
      [xjc] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that XJC won't do unnecessary compilation
      [xjc] Compiling file:/C:/Program Files/opt/i2b2 Softwares/i2b2core-src-1707/edu.harvard.i2b2.xml/xsd/cell/pm_1.1/PM_USER.xsd and other
s
      [xjc] Writing output to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc

compile:
    [javac] C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\build.xml:60: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set
, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 95 source files to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes
    [javac] Note: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\test\edu\harvard\i2b2\pm\ws\PMAxisAbstract.java
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

axis2aar:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist\ProjectManagement.aar

common_init:

common-classpath:

init:

jaxb_gen:
      [xjc] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that XJC won't do unnecessary compilation
      [xjc] Compiling file:/C:/Program Files/opt/i2b2 Softwares/i2b2core-src-1707/edu.harvard.i2b2.xml/xsd/cell/pm_1.1/PM_USER.xsd and other
s
      [xjc] Writing output to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\gensrc

compile:
    [javac] C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\build.xml:60: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set
, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 48 source files to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\classes

jar_core:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\dist\ProjectManagement-core.jar

deploy:
     [echo] ProjectManagement: Copying archive package to app server C:Program Filesoptjboss-as-7.1.1.Final
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\Program Filesoptjboss-as-7.1.1.Final
\standalone\deployments\i2b2.war\WEB-INF\lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\Program Filesoptjboss-as-7.1.1.Final
\standalone\deployments
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Program Files\opt\i2b2 Softwares\i2b2core-src-1707\edu.harvard.i2b2.pm\Program Filesoptjboss-as-7.1.1.Final
\standalone\deployments\i2b2.war\WEB-INF\services

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 14 seconds
```

Could anyone please tell me what troubleshooting steps I must take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `standalone.xml` located in the JBoss must have the following ports for the localhost:

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="9009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="9090"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```